How to p4 sync files without creating a client
In a CI/CD pipeline, I need to pull some files from a Perforce repo. I am very new to p4. Only way I know is to p4 client create a client, then p4 sync.
But in the pipeline, I feel I may not create a client every time when the pipeline runs. How can I sync files with only a list of view files but without creating a client?

You can use the p4 print command, e.g.:
p4 print -o ... //depot/dir/...

Note that these locally written files are not tracked by p4, so you will need to delete them yourself after you're done with them.
